# Is a viewshed reversible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, visualisation

I want to understand what is visible by a human observer standing in a particular location. Therefore, I have conducted a visibility analysis in ArcGIS with a DEM, using an observer offset of 1.75m to model the humans (Human A) height.

However, I also want to know if Human A is visible by other humans standing anywhere in the surrounding landscape. So I am really asking if the viewshed I have constructed works both ways i.e. that if Human A can see a point in the landscape, another person at that point would be also be able to see the location of Human A? Or to do this do I need to add a surface offset of 1.75m to apply the other humans height to every other cell?

Comment: The ability to see a location does not always imply that a human will be observed at that location. Colors, patterns, relative size, and motion all play a role in observability, and modeling these with GIS tools would be challenging indeed.

Comment: Just reading the help on the [Line of Sight](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-line-of-sight-works.htm#:~:text=The%20Line%20Of%20Sight%20tool,last%20is%20the%20observation%20target.) tool (2nd paragraph), it says an offset value of "1" is added to the observer. From that, I'd assume the offset is critical (knowing when/if it's automatically applied and adding it when not)

Comment: A viewshed is not formally reversible in your case. Even though it can be very close from reversible depending on the distances involved. It also depends : what does it mean that a person can be seen ? I would say that the ground (person feet) needs to be visible. Looking a the Arcgis Spatial Analyst Viewshed documentation, the output raster can provide Output AGL: "height needed in each cell to be visible" from the central observer. In that case, you can figure out where the central observer (set at 0m) can be seen: from any point from the Output AGL raster with value <1.75m

Comment: Thank you.I think I may have confused it.  I am studying the site of an ancient building. I am modelling what a person could see from that location before the temple was constructed, thus 1.75m offset for human height in the viewshed I think works in terms of modelling what that person could have seen. However, I also want to know if the location (not the human) of the site which he stood, was visible from the landscape.

Comment: Therefore, assume that if I add a surface offset of 1.75m this should add this elevation to each cell, and that as long as I also remove the elevation of the human on the site, then this would model visibility of the point at which I conducted the viewshed from the surrounding landscape?

Comment: If you offset the surface by 1.75m, obstacles will be offset as well. The method I suggested in my previous comment should work: viewshed from the building site with no observer elevation, and only retain viewshed rater points with Output AGL =< 1.75. This should give you places where an observer  could see the ground at the building site before it was constructed

Comment: Thank you Kasper, I will try this later on.

Comment: Many thanks I ran the AGL as suggested. I am not sure how to change the symbology to reflect the AGL<1.75. The default output is Classify. Method: Normal interval. Classes =10. But the lowest upper value is 200